# Spinner Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, json

¿Cómo hago para mostrar un valor que se recibe de una base de datos en el spinner?;
Es decir, el registro ya tiene guardado la opción que seleccionó el usuario. ¿Cómo mostrar esa opción en el spinner al consultar el registro?

```
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        spi_tipo.setSelection(jsonObject.getString("tipoIncidencia"));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
```

En la app para escritorio se realiza de la siguiente manera:

```
cbox_area.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("area"));
```

¿Cuál es su equivalente en Java para Móvil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tan sencillo como ir a mirar en la ayuda de la clase `Spinner`. La función se llama `setSelection` y tienes que pasarle la posición del elemento que quieres seleccionar, empezando en `0`:

```
tu_spinner.setSelection( posicion);
```

Ahora, ¿cómo saber en qué posición está un texto concreto, si lo que recibes de la base de datos es un texto? Pues eso ya dependerá de cómo creaste el Spinner, cómo le diste los valores, cómo los guardas en la base de datos y cómo los recuperas.